# When to use position sticky with css?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I've never used the `position: sticky;` and found this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) but couldn't understand that when should I use this position. Can anyone visualise this position?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit . But i don't think it is supported yet as it is labeled as "experimental" and says you should not use it in production code.

Answer (score 4):

As described in the [acticle](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit):

> position: sticky is a new way to position elements and is conceptually
> similar to position: fixed. The difference is that an element with
> position: sticky behaves like position: relative within its parent,
> until a given offset threshold is met in the viewport.

It is basically the same as `position: fixed` but the sticky element can't go out of the parent element. With the offset position of top you set a property of when the sticky element should scroll with the page. So for example when the top is set to 10px it will scroll with the page when top is 10px away of your window screen:

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

**It has not been implented yet.** However you can test this experimental property.

In chrome you can enable the enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag by just following this link:
*about://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features*

### [Example page of the acticle](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)

---

You can use a Jquery plugin to mimic this behaviour: [stickyfill](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill)

Comment: Like jquery sticky scroll box  ?

Comment: @zey yea, it basically works the same :) Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

From the [verry same source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) you read about 'sticky'

> **sticky** (This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code.)
>
> The box position is calculated according to the normal flow (this is called the position in normal flow). Then the box is offset
>   relative to its flow root and containing block and in all cases,
>   including table elements, does not affect the position of any
>   following boxes. When a box B is stickily positioned, the position of
>   the following box is calculated as though B were not offset. The
>   effect of ‘position: sticky’ on table elements is the same as for
>   ‘position: relative’.

Mouse over that icon on the same page
[image]

Other references about usability :

- http://caniuse.com/#search=position (no sticky there)
- http://caniuse.com/#search=stic (no sticky there either)